# Special unicode characters in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, unicode

I'm trying to copy the Unicode character ♭ (U+266D) into Adobe Illustrator CS6, but it's not showing up correctly. It shows up as a tall rectangle with an X inside.

Mac Keynote and other apps have no problem displaying the character. How can I get it to show up correctly in Illustrator?

Comment: You need to choose a font that contains that glyph. Not all fonts do. Something like DejaVu Sans for example.

Comment: That works, thanks! Here are more fonts listed: https://graphemica.com/%E2%99%AD